# UICollectionViewCell Shadow on all four sides

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, dropshadow

I was wondering want the best way to add drop shadows to a set of collectionviewcells that do not have spaces between them?

**Background**

Part of my layout has various cells positioned across the screen like a post. It notes and the second half of the layout is structured to look like a `tableview` except all the cells don't go to the edges there's a bit of padding. So I can't really add a shadow around the collection view itself.

I have added shadows to the cells in the post. It note part which works great because the cells have spaces between them but I'm now struggling with the second half (the `tableview` looking part) because obviously when you add the shadows to the cells depending on the zIndex you may see the shadow overlapping the below or top cell.

So I was wondering what is the best way to do this?

Should the shadows decoration views underneath the cells?

**OR**
 
Should the shadows be attached to the cell and increase the ZIndex for each cell so they appear on different levels hiding the shadow - but that leads to a question on how to do the first cell and have a top shadow?

**OR**
Should I almost fake it by using an image of a shadow inside the cell itself?

I also have deletion functionality so I need to figure out how to make sure if I delete the first cell, the second cell should then have the top shadow in a nice animated way.

EDIT:

I am trying to create the following view inside the collection view.  I have got the layout correct. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUkII.png)

The green lines are the shadows I have working but the red are the ones I'm having trouble with and the boxes are the different cells.

Comment: I would add the shadow inside the cell on the top of the cell and hide the shadow if this is the first cell on the Table/Collection View

Comment: So where do you want the shadows to appear if it "looks like a tableview" with no padding between cells?
You could of course add padding and then shadows between them if that's what you want...

Comment: Lefteris do you mean you would use the images or add drop shadow to a subview?

Comment: Unixb0y - what i am looking for is something that looks like  a shadow around the entire group of cells that our touching.  Also unfortunately I can't add space between the cells as the UI designs don't allow for it so would require more discussions.

Comment: Can you please attach a mockup of how you want the UI to look?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post to include a link with a very rough diagram